# Get sentence containing specific word with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find the sentence that contains a specific word.
I defined a sentence starting and ending with the following characters :`. ! ?`

```
var str = "Hello, how is it going. This is the bus we have to take!";
var regex = /[^.?!]*(?:[.?,\s!])(bus)(?=[\s.?!,])[^.?!]*[.?!]/igm;

var result = regex.exec(str);


output : `This is the bus we have to take!`
```

Now, I have trouble when I try to find the sentence that contains the word `hello`, as it's starting the sentence. How could I change my regex to include that case? I am not used to regex and it's quite hard to get into it, even with the docs under my eyes!

Comment: if you're defining a sentence break with ,.!? then why not split the string on those and then loop over them checking a simpler regex? If you get a hit then output the sentence that got the hit.

Comment: I was considering that option, but I was also wondering if I can do that in one regex. But I probably should do what you just said

Comment: If you want to experiment further, try [`/[^.?!]*\bhello\b[^.?!]*/ig`](https://regex101.com/r/yyfMa9/1), but this is not a valid way to extract *sentences*, you need an NLP package for that.

Comment: I would follow @markg 's advice. Split the string on .?! and match on .*(bus).*

Comment: You do not need a regex to check for `bus`, just check it with `indexOf`.

Comment: You only need start of string ^ and end of line $ to delimit a sentence. (a sentence could contain a question: "to be or not to be? That's the question). 


    ^(.*bus.*)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that splitting text into *linguistic sentences* is a very specific, difficult task usually performed with the help of NLP packages.

If you want to limit to specific strings that follow your definition of a sentence:

- Split with `/[.?!]/` regex
- Check if the entry contains a substring with `RegExp#test()` since you need a case insensitive check

```js
var str = "Hello, how is it going. This is the bus we have to take!";
var chunks = str.split(/[.?!]/).filter(function(n) {
  return /hello/i.test(n);
});
console.log(chunks);
```

Note that to check for a whole word you may use `/\bhello\b/i`  or `/(?:^|\s)hello(?!\S)/i` regexps depending on further requirements.